# How to create a new tab within tabbed item in SWT java

Tags: java, swt

We are trying to improvise our application UI, which written using SWT java. I have a scenario where I need to create different tabs for each connection with the database.

Within a connection, I may be required to create a table or view. This creation of a table should come as a tabbed item within the parent tab. how to achieve this. I'm very new to SWT java, any suggestions are most welcome. thanks in advance.

I have created the parent tab with TabFolder and adding child tab is adding next to parent tab.

```
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        TabFolder folder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.TOP);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
        folder.setLayoutData(data);
        folder.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
        TabItem cTabItem1 = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem1.setText("firstPage");
        TabItem cTabItem2 = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem2.setText("NConn");

        Composite parentComposite = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);
        parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        cTabItem2.setControl(parentComposite);    

        Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        tableComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));


      Button createButton = new Button(tableComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        createButton.setText("Cr Tbl");
        createButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        createButton.addSelectionListener((new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                CreateTable.createTableUI(folder);
            }
        }));


        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();


CreatTable.java


        TabItem item = new TabItem(tableComposite, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Create Table");
        Composite c = new Composite(tableComposite, SWT.NONE);
        item.setControl(c);
        c.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(c, SWT.BOTTOM);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
        folder.setLayoutData(data);
        // folder.setSelectionForeground(tableComposite1.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        CTabItem cTabItem1 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem1.setText("Columns");
        CTabItem cTabItem2 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem2.setText("Indexes");
```

Need to create a child tab within a parent tab.

Comment: There are too many undefined things in this code. Show us a proper [mcve]

Comment: @greg-449 added the code

Comment: I'm not clear what this code is trying to do. It seems to add a third tab to the main TabFolder.

Comment: @greg-449, yes currently i'm adding 3rd tab(newly created tab) to main tab. I need to add newly created tab as a child tab to the main tab.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not able fully understand what is the problem. I took your code done some changes. Look the output image is that you are looking for?

```
public class MainClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        TabFolder parentTab = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.TOP);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
        parentTab.setLayoutData(data);
        parentTab.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
        TabItem cTabItem1 = new TabItem(parentTab, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem1.setText("firstPage");
        TabItem cTabItem2 = new TabItem(parentTab, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem2.setText("NConn");

        Composite parentComposite = new Composite(parentTab, SWT.NONE);
        parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        cTabItem2.setControl(parentComposite);

        Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        tableComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL).applyTo(tableComposite);

        Button createButton = new Button(tableComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        createButton.setText("Cr Tbl");
        createButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
        createButton.addSelectionListener((new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                CreateTable.createTableUI(tableComposite);
                tableComposite.layout();
                tableComposite.getParent().update();
            }
        }));

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

CreateTable code

```
public class CreateTable {

    public static void createTableUI(Composite tabbedComp) {
        Composite c = new Composite(tabbedComp, SWT.NONE);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL).applyTo(c);
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(c, SWT.BOTTOM);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
        folder.setLayoutData(data);
        // folder.setSelectionForeground(tableComposite1.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        CTabItem cTabItem1 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem1.setText("Columns");
        CTabItem cTabItem2 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        cTabItem2.setText("Indexes");
    }
}
```

> Output: To generate this output I clicked button twice

[image: Output]